# Magento list all products out of stock after showing all products in stock the day before

Tags: php, magento, permissions, catalog, promotions

I'm using the latest version of Magento, 1.9.1.1, and when I went to check my shopping cart this morning all of my products are out of stock on the retail side. Each product still shows "yes" for "Stock Availability" with a quantity listed > 0 on the "Inventory" tab within the product configuration in Magento.

If you login to the shopping cart with a wholesale account the products are in stock, but if you login on the retail side with a account setup as retail there still are no products in stock. I'm using "Catalog Permissions" from Aheadworks to separate the retail store from the wholesale store.

I have about a 100 products and the only thing I configured and setup on the backend within the last day that this problem started happening is the extension "Promotions Pro".

I have re-indexed everything on the "Index Management" page and refreshed all the caches.

Comment: you can ask for support from aheadworks

Comment: There's a Magento specific stack-exchange; post that question there. This is not a programming-related question.

Comment: I posted this question in the Magento stack-exchange and I also contacted Aheadworks. Thanks you.